# How to determine alignment / correlation with comparison based judgments?

Tags: accuracy, human-like, metric, correlation

I have built an automatic metric (using DL) to estimate some property of text. I want to evaluate its performance by comparing it to human judgments with respect to that property. As far as I know this is usually done using correlation. I found a related data sets. The problem is that the property is not annotated on an absolute scale but with comparisons.

Imagine for example something like this:

```
Text_A < Text_B < Text_C;
Text_D < Text_B < Text_D;
...
```

(The text are ranked according to the property. Each Text can occur in multiple compares, but I think not everything is compared with everything.)

So the question is: **What is the way to get the correlation? (Or what is the best way to judge the alignment?)**

I would be happy about every hint (including suggestions to improve the question)!

---

Further Information:

- I assume such data might originate from using Best-worst scaling (but that's not explicitly stated in the source).
- I assume using a rank based correlation fits more than the standard correlation.

---

My attempts:

- An idea is to **average the correlations** of each set of compares. But I haven't found a way to perform the average in an exact way. Fisher z transformation seems to be only an estimate and as I have a lot of individual correlations with just 3 data points each, I assume the bias would be quite significant. **Does anybody know a way to exactly average correlations for sets of equal size?**
- I was thinking about using **accuracy** instead of correlation, as it seems easier to aggregate. Just convert everything into binary compares:

  Text_A < Text_B < Text_C;

  ->

  Text_A < Text_B; Text_B < Text_C; Text_A < Text_C;

  But I am not sure whether this is appropriated. **What are advantages of accuracy and correlation, why would one prefer one over the other? What is their relationship?**

  Using a small R experiment I figured out that accuracy and correlation seem to be closely aligned but not perfect, see [code on github](https://github.com/UntotaufUrlaub/cor_vs_acc/blob/main/fiddle.R). (The experiments did not consider ties in the the simulated ranking data.)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with converting the compares to an absolute scale using something like ELO scoring from chess ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system), [a paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-017-0898-2)), than you can just use correlation as usual.